# bash: ./mysql_exe.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: mysql, bash

everyone.

I'm a bash script noob, and I'm failing to figure out why I'm getting an unexpected end of file error.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

server=8100

while [ $server -le 8121 ]
do
        ssh pos$server <<ENDEXP
        mysql -u root -p12345 pos_master_prod <<ENDEXP
        show slave status \G <<ENDEXP
        \q <<ENDEXP
        server=$(( $server + 1 ))
done
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what it's supposed to do, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((server=8100; server <= 8121; server++)); do
    ssh pos$server <<-ENDEXP
        mysql -u root -p12345 pos_master_prod
        show slave status \G
        \q
    ENDEXP
done
```

(Note: be sure the lines to be sent to the remote server are indented with tabs, not spaces; `<<-` removes leading tabs, but not other forms of indentation.)

Comment: Yes!! That did it! Thank you so much! Can you explain what was wrong with mine so I better understand why my script didn't work?

Again, thank you!

Comment: Just looks like I had terrible syntax really. :)

Comment: @SquireCD: The only problem you had was the here-document syntax: don't put `<<DELIMITER` on each line, put it on the command before the here-doc, then put `DELIMITER` alone on a line after the here-doc.  Adding a dash (`<<-DELIMITER`) tells it to remove leading tabs, and quoting the delimiter will keep it from replacing `$variable` expressions in the here-doc.  The reason yours worked without the loop is that it never saw the delimiter (`ENDEXP`) alone on a line, so it just used to the end of the script.  With the loop, that meant it couldn't find the `done` command, and panicked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use a [here-doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) but the syntax is a bit off..

Comment: This works without the while loop.
If I do ./mysql_exe.sh 8104, it'll get the slave status of server 8104. I just can't seem to get it to automate.